# Generate icon font from SVG images using Maven

Tags: java, maven, icons, webfonts, icon-fonts

I'm working on a java webapp that uses icon fonts for the icons.
I know I can create an icon font from individual SVG files using the IcoMoon app, but I don't want to manually have to recreate the font each time an icon needs to be added.
So I want to do it automatically, preferably as part of the Maven build.  Is there a way to let Maven generate the icon font from the individual SVG files?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a maven plugin to perform that specific function.

I'd suggest you use grunt 
http://gruntjs.com/
which runs on node and the grunt web font plugin
https://github.com/sapegin/grunt-webfont

If you created your `GruntFile.js` in src/main/resources/grunt

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
//Project Configuration
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'), //Details about the package were creating 
    webfont: {
        icons: {
            src : "icons/svg/*.svg",
            dest: '../META-INF/resources/font',
            destCss:'../META-INF/resources/css',
            options: {
                font: 'myfont',
                fontFilename: 'MyFont',
                types:'eot,woff,ttf,svg',
                engine:'node',
                stylesheet:'less',
                htmlDemo:false
            }
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-webfont');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['webfont']);
};
```

You can then in your pom run

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>Grunt run</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>grunt</executable>
                        <workingDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/grunt</workingDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

You probably want to exclude src/main/resources/grunt from maven resources and make sure that the icon file doesn't go through maven resource filtering as that tends to break them.